# Allow Html Content to be posted

Tags: asp.net

Recently i have faced an interview question.

You have finished an ASP.NET application using .NET framework 3.5.
You plan to submit text that contains HTML code to a page in the application.
You need to ensure that the HTML code can be submitted successfully without affecting other applications that run on the web server.
What would be your option?

1. Add the following in Web.Config

   ```
   <system.web>
     <pages validateRequest="false"/>
   </system.web>
   ```
2. Add the following in Machine.Config

   ```
   <system.web>
     <pages validateRequest="false"/>
   </system.web>
   ```

I guess the correct answer could be (1). Just wish to confirm the answer from SO experts. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is correct. by putting the code in machine.config you will affect the whole machine as this are global settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can also decorate the single action method with

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This will result in more security because you have the
control when request validation happens.

Comment: This is only applicable to MVC apps, of course. Won't work for Web Forms.

Answer (score 2):

> You plan to submit text that contains HTML code to a page in the
>   application.

Since it's just "**a** page," it would be much better to disable validation checking for that page alone, rather than for the entire application (web.config), much less for all apps on that server (machine.config).

To do that, set ValidateRequest="false" on the @Page directive.

Answer (score 0):

> without affecting other applications that run on the web server

This is the key, web.config will only affect the one application.  Wheras machine.config will affect all over applications running on the server.